# "TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, cookies

I have this tiny bit of code here, but it is not functioning when I reload the page, as I get the error

> TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
>
> document.getElementById('devMode_checkbox').checked = false;

The line(s) the error is referring to is as follows:

```
checkDevMode();
        
        function checkDevMode() {

            var devModeIsTrue = getCookie('devModeIsTrue');
            if (devModeIsTrue === true) {
                
                document.getElementById('devMode_checkbox').checked = true;
                enableDevMode(devModeIsTrue);
                
            } else {
                
                document.getElementById('devMode_checkbox').checked = false;

            }
        }
```

I have quadruple checked the id of the element

```
<input type='checkbox' onchange='enableDevMode(this.checked)' id='devMode_checkbox'>
```

and I don't really have a good understanding nor a solution for this problem. Also I could not find a working solution for this. (Sorry if this is a duplicate, but non of the given answers worked for me)

Is there a (proper) solution to this?

Comment: is the `checkDevMode` function called after the element exists?

Comment: No, it is all run from the `<head>`

Comment: that's the problem

Comment: So, I have to run the script after the element is declared? If so, can I declare the function before the element and call it afterwards, or does the function also have to be declared after the element is declared

Comment: have a look at the linked question. theres many options.